# ValueError: math domain error in math.log()

Tags: python-3.x

I have a trouble with math.log in Python. I am trying to calculate a probability equation, but I do not know why it keeps showing the error even though the result is correct. Can someone see any issue in my code below?

```
import math
import numpy
def calc_snp_log_odds(readData):
pobs = numpy.prod([i[0] for i in readData])
pobs1 = numpy.prod([i[1] for i in readData])
logOdds = (math.log(pobs*0.8+pobs1*0.2) + math.log(0.001)) - (math.log(pobs) + math.log(0.999))
return logOdds
```

the result should be `-1.6144554844260801`
error:

`Failed test #2. Runtime error
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "jailed_code", line 17, in <module>
 logOdds = calc_snp_log_odds(readData)
 File "jailed_code", line 8, in calc_snp_log_odds
 logOdds = (math.log(pobs*0.8+pobs1*0.2) + math.log(0.001)) -     (math.log(pobs) + math.log(0.999))
 ValueError: math domain error`

Comment: print the values of `pobs` and `pobs1` - it's impossible for us to guess what they are

Comment: the value of pobs is 0.001 and pobs1 is 0.99.

Comment: This could happen if you are taking the log of a number that is very close to zero. I substituted `pobs=0.001`, `pobs2=0.99` but didn't get an error. You might want to print out the values of all the numbers that you are taking a `log` of.